# Executing `find` using `std::process::Command` on cygwin does not work

Tags: cygwin, rust

When I try to call the `find` command from a Rust program, either I get a `FIND: Invalid switch` or a `FIND: Parameter format incorrect` error.

`find` works fine from command line.

```
echo $PATH

/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:.....
```

The file I am searching for (`main.rs`) exists.

```
use std::process::{Stdio,Command};
use std::io::{Write};

fn main() {
    let mut cmd_find = Command::new("/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin/find.exe")
        .arg("/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/*")
        .stdin(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .unwrap_or_else(|e| { panic!("failed to execute process:  {}", e)});

    if let Some(ref mut stdin) = cmd_find.stdin {
        stdin.write_all(b"main.rs").unwrap();   
    }       

    let res = cmd_find.wait_with_output().unwrap().stdout;  
    println!("{}",String::from_utf8_lossy(&res));
}
```

> ./find_cmdd.exe
>
> `thread '<main>' panicked at 'failed to execute process:  The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2)', find_cmdd.rs:12`

I have also tried the following option,

```
let mut cmd_find = Command::new("find").....
```

for which I get `FIND:Invalid switch` error.

I do not have the luxury of renaming/copying the `find.exe` to another location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cygwin basically doesn't exist when you are running a program via `Command`. Executing a process uses the operating system's native functionality; in the case of Windows [that's `CreateProcessW`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.10.0/src/libstd/sys/windows/process.rs#L203-L208).

That means that:

1. The `PATH` variable set by your cygwin shell may or may not mean anything when starting a process.
2. The directory structure with `/cygdrive/...` doesn't actually exist in Windows; that's an artifact.

All that said, you have to use Windows-native paths:

```
use std::process::{Stdio, Command};
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    let mut cmd_find = Command::new(r#"\msys32\usr\bin\find.exe"#)
        .args(&[r#"\msys32\home"#])
        .stdin(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .unwrap_or_else(|e| panic!("failed to execute process:  {}", e));

    if let Some(ref mut stdin) = cmd_find.stdin {
        stdin.write_all(b"main.rs").unwrap();
    }

    let res = cmd_find.wait_with_output().unwrap().stdout;
    println!("{}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&res));
}
```

As a side note, I have no idea what piping standard input to `find` does; it doesn't seem to have any effect for me on Msys2 or on OS X...

Comment: Thanks Shepmaster!

Answer (score 2):

"FIND:Invalid switch error" indicates this is NOT the cygwin `find`, but you are invoking the Windows one. To double check:

```
$ find -k
find: unknown predicate `-k'

$ /cygdrive/c/windows/system32/find -k
FIND: Parameter format not correct
```

Comment: Hi Matzeri, I agree the windows find is being invoked. As I have pointed out, the PATH variable holds the Cygwin bin directory, before the windows path, so am not sure how the windows find is getting invoked, but   how do I invoke or use the Cygwin find command in my program??

Comment: Again as I have pointed out, I have tried using, ("/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin/find) ...which seems to be of no use.