# Why isn't this command running properly?

Tags: rust

So I'm making a better command-line frontend for APT and I'm putting on some finishing touches and when the code below runs.

```rust
Command::new("unbuffer")
    .arg("apt")
    .arg("list")
    .arg("|")
    .arg("less")
    .arg("-r")
    .status()
    .expect("Something went wrong.");
```

it spits out:

```
E: Command line option 'r' [from -r] is not understood in combination with the other options.
```

but when I just run `unbuffer apt list | less -r` manually in my terminal it works perfectly. How do I get it to run properly when calling it in Rust?

Comment: `|` is not an argument in bash

Comment: @Bergi how do I use `|` then? Also I'm using zsh lol

Comment: Why do you need the pipe (`|`)?  The `less` command is usually used for pagination within the terminal. Most likely you want the entire output from the `unbuffer apt list` command to be parsed by Rust, no? If so, leave off the pipe and everything after it.

Comment: I'll guess you have to use [the `pipe` crate](https://docs.rs/os_pipe/0.8.1/os_pipe/fn.pipe.html) for that.

Comment: A hack would be to just [send the entire script to a bash command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38551671/1048572) :-)

Comment: Or maybe it's much easier: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/index.html#handling-io

Answer (score 3):

Spawning a process via `Command` uses the system's native functionality to create a process. This is a low level feature and has little to do with your shell/terminal that you are used to. In particular, your shell (e.g. `bash` or `zsh`, running inside of your terminal) offers a lot more features. For example, piping via `|` is such a feature. `Command` does not support these features as the low level system's API doesn't.

Luckily, the low level interface offers other means of achieving a lot of stuff. Piping for example is mostly just redirecting the standard inputs and outputs. You can do that with `Command::{stdin, stdout, sterr}`. Please see [this part of the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/index.html#handling-io) for more information.

There are a few very similar questions, which are not similar enough to warrent closing this as a dupe though:

- [Execute a shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31666936/execute-a-shell-command)
- [Why does the compgen command work in the Linux terminal but not with process::Command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49928601/why-does-the-compgen-command-work-in-the-linux-terminal-but-not-with-processco): mentions shell built-in commands that do not work with `Command`.
- [Executing `find` using `std::process::Command` on cygwin does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38847641/executing-find-using-stdprocesscommand-on-cygwin-does-not-work)